# Programmatically know if the current font has the powerline patch

Tags: vim, fonts, zsh, fish

I use vim with [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) that can use [*patched fonts*](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) for additional awesomeness.

[image: vim-airline]

I also use [`fish`](https://fishshell.com) shell (if you want read `zsh` here since it is equivalent for the analysis) with a theme that also uses patched fonts.

I save my dotfiles online and I use them in different systems. But in some of them I don't have a patched font.
I would really love to have generic dotfiles that for example do not use a theme that needs patched font if the current font is not patched. Also in my `vimrc` I disabled the use of patched characters for vim-airline because of this.

Is there a way to programmatically know if the font that is currently in use is a patched one so that is possible to write generic dotfiles that fit perfectly in all the situations?

Comment: That is _ridiculously_ cool. One approach might be to just programmatically patch the font: https://github.com/powerline/fontpatcher (looking at that may be a source of clues to solving the problem you actually asked, too)

Comment: Actually, reading this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140327/can-we-patch-an-already-patched-font it sounds like running the patcher on an already-patched font is a no-op. You might, therefore, be able to do what you want by copying the font file, patching it, and comparing md5sum to the original. If the file didn't change it was already patched, if it did then it isn't.

Comment: If you're going to go as far as copying the patched file to the system, you may as well go the extra step and just configure your terminal emulator there to use the patched font.

Answer (score 5):

In Vim, you would need to directly ask your terminal emulator what font it is currently using. The exact method will certainly be different from terminal to terminal and from OS to OS. If that's even possible.

If you have it on all your systems, you could use `lsof` to find what font is currently used by a given program:

```
$ lsof | grep iTerm | grep '\.\(otf\|ttf\)'
```

In GVim/MacVim, you would check if the current font name matches some pattern with something like:

```
if &guifont =~? 'powerline'
    " do something
else
    " do something else
endif
```

And that's *assuming* your font's filename contains that pattern.

But it's impossible to guarantee that an actual "powerline font" has `powerline` in its file name and it's equally impossible to guarantee that a font with `powerline` in its file name is an actual "powerline font".

It would be safer to check for the presence of the `Powerline` string somewhere in the font with something like:

```
$ xxd ~/Downloads/FuraMono-Bold\ Powerline.otf | grep Powerline
```

But that's assuming:

- `xxd` is available,
- you were able to derive the path of the actual font from whatever info you managed to gather from your terminal emulator or from GVim/MacVim.

That's a lot of assumptions and seemingly a lot of work for something as superficial as a "powerline font".

Comment: Vim comes with xxd, but the rest of this is valid :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this the other way around and only enable Powerline fonts for known machines in your .vimrc e.g.

```
let hostname = substitute(system('hostname'), '\n', '', '')
let patched_font_hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']   " List of know patched hosts
if(index(patched_font_hosts, hostname) >= 0)
  let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
endif
```

It's easier to know which hosts you have patched and it's not a really a problem if the list is not up to date.